# Help needed on Metadata API or Tooling API

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api

Has anyone used Metadata API or Tooling API to bulk update Workflow, Validation Rule etc? I am trying to play with these 2 API using SOAP UI but not sure if that's feasible. Any guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Updating Workflow using Tooling API and Metadata API is feasible in following conditions and consideration:-

1. Workflow in not time dependent
2. If workflow reference a user, it must be present in organisation where the workflow in being updated.
3. You have all dependencies existing in system or in deployment payload.
4. Tooling API don't have [Workflow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm) object, it has its child objects.

Validation rules have no issues either you use tooling api or metadata API.

**Which one to use?**
Tooling API is easy to build over but lack some operations. Metadata API is time consumng but has all required operations. You may use Tooling and Metadata API together to achieve the functionality.

Comment: actually ,I found the link for Workflow object in Tooling API [link]https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowrule.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please check following Git link,

https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

This repo covers some of the basic metadata API call examples. Please let me know if this doesn't help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link Tushar. I will go through it and let you know.